# Работа пхп-функции intval()

Tags: php

Не могу понять, почему

```
echo intval(42, 8);
```

возвращает 42, а

```
echo intval('42', 8);
```

возвращает 34.
Вроде в обоих функциях задано, что основание числа 8.

Comment: @Heidel, если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из мануала: "аргумент base для intval() не имеет эффекта, если только аргумент var не является строкой."

Comment: ясно, спасибо. в моем учебнике просто приведен код безо всякого пояснениях.

Answer (score 3):

base учитывается только, если первый параметр строка.

[intval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php)